# Will any sugar substitutes brown in a crumble topping?

Tags: baking, sugar-free

As a diabetic (but unfortunately with a sweet tooth!!), I would welcome any recommendations for a sweetener as a substitute for sugar which will allow browning as in the topping for a fruit crumble.

Comment: You could reduce the use of real sugar (if that is acceptable) by using two thin layers of crumble, the lower using whatever sugar substitute you prefer and the upper with real sugar. Even in the top layer, you could experiment with mixtures of real sugar and sweetener...

Answer (score 1):

As breadcrumbs in a savoury topping brown quite nicely (and so does unsweetened pastry) I should think you'd be able to find a mix that would work.

The recipe would probably involve both fat and some sort of starchy ingredient(s). You might need to switch from oven to grill for a few minutes when it's cooked to get *enough* browning -- and getting just the right amount of browning might be harder, as some ingredients might burn quite suddenly. Of course, only browned sugar tastes like browned sugar (unless you can find a suitable caramel additive).

Perhaps a good place to start would be a "flapjack crumble" recipe, modified in a similar way to the many sugar-free flapjack recipes out there.  A crumble topping that's more like pastry crumbs should also do work but the texture is likely to be less forgiving.